# How can I make my app fit to most screens?

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android-linearlayout

My app is big for my small phone screen , and what happens is that some items appear small or out of place . Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: *"The Xamarin.Forms FlexLayout is new in Xamarin.Forms version 3.0. It is based on the CSS Flexible Box Layout Module, commonly known as flex layout or flex-box, so called because it includes many flexible options to arrange children within the layout."* [The Xamarin.Forms FlexLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout)

Comment: Basically iám saying study [Layouts in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/)

Comment: I cant find flexlayout in xamarin.android @RaymondNijland

Comment: is it called something else on xamarin.android?

Comment: Dont think so see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/